# Create repo for pull/push code in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator, push-diffusion

I installed Phabricator on my system. I also want to Host and Browse Repository feature in it. I used Diffusion feature but unable to figure out URL I should use to pull or push code.

Additional documentation:

- https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_uris/
- https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries. In settings of repo i.e. in URI section it automatically creating both ssh and http url. 
May i didnt configure it properly after installation and hence was not showing initially.

Comment: So what exactly was the configuration that was wrong and which one is right ?